# Priority two apps use bootcompletedReceiver on android

Tags: android

recently I use `BOOT_COMPLETED` 2 app (A app, and B app)

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
</intent-filter>
```

A app is activity and B app is service app

when my device boot, 
first A app launch and B app launch 
so, show B app screen.

I want 
first B app launch and A app launch  showing A app screen

perhaps, Can I give `BOOT_COMPLETED` Priority is possible?

finally, I want when I boot my device,  show A app screen

Thanks!

add

I try

B app(service)

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) {
   Intent i = new Intent("A app package  name.BOOT_COMPLETED");
   context.sendBroadcast(i);
   }
 }
}


<receiver android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver"
              android:enabled="true"
              android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

A app(activity)

```
public class BootSendReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent) {
    if( intent.getAction().equals("B app packagename.BOOT_COMPLETED"));
   Intent i = new Intent (context, MainActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(i);

}
}




    <receiver android:name=".BootSendReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="blackeyeonandroid.iosystem.co.kr.simpleserviceexample.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and I try boot .. but showing B app screen

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not control that..

Instead, you can make APP1 start the APP2. This way, only APP1 receives the BOOT_COMPLETE message. Then, APP1 is responsible to send a new intent to start APP2:

Maybe, you can do as follows (note that APP2 does not receive android's default BOOT_COMPLETED message):

**APP1**

Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <receiver android:name=".AppToStartFirstBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Receiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Intent i = new Intent("com.example.mytestapp.BOOT_COMPLETED");
        context.sendBroadcast(i);
    }
}
```

**APP2**

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".AppToStartLaterBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.mytestapp.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Receiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("com.example.mytestapp.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        // Do what you want in secundary APP
    }
}
```

**Note**

This is an suggestion and you should adjust to your case. Since I don't have more details about your code, you may need to modify it to your case.. But you can use the idea.

Comment: this way,  app1 start first,    and app2 start?

Comment: I add question  How you declaration `LOG`, `mContext`?

Comment: Yes. App1 will start first because only app1 will receive boot notification. Then, app1 will start app2....

Comment: I update the answer... sorry.. I inserted unnecessary code... now I remove it.. sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: thanks but not work .   please check question update